# Is it possible to get multiple table data into single page

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

I want to get multiple table data into a page. 
Actually, I am trying to get table data according to its page id.

```
                   $page = $_GET['v'];                               
                   if($page == 1){
                        $sel_data="SELECT * FROM fix ORDER BY fix_id DESC ";
                        $qri_res=mysqli_query($con,$sel_data);
                    }

                    if($page == 2){
                        $sel_data="SELECT * FROM seo ORDER BY   seo_id DESC ";
                        $qri_res=mysqli_query($con,$sel_data);
                    }                                                
                    if($page == 3){
                        $sel_data="SELECT * FROM err ORDER BY   err_id DESC ";
                        $qri_res=mysqli_query($con,$sel_data);
                    }          
                   while($total_row=mysqli_fetch_array($qri_res)){
```

but it resulting me only first one. Please help me to solve this out.

Comment: what do you mean by first one? the first query or a single row?

Comment: What are you doing here? Why do you call another table for each page?

Comment: may be $page  is 1 so it's always executing 1st query

Comment: Can you explain whats your goal here?Can you give the tables and the output that you want.I'm not sure might be a simple join can solve this.But i can't tell you anything by this poorly explained question.

Comment: My goal is to get multiple table data according to its page id,That means if the page id == 1 it should fetch the table 1 data.is it possible?? @Arslan.H

Comment: It's posible but you are approaching it the wrong way.Post your tables,probably they are also wrong.Make a detailed questions of whats your goal,I'l write down a whole small tutorial if i can call it like that.Also don't use mysqli use PDO.As i see in this code you have more problems that you have taught of....

Comment: first query @Exprator is there any other way to get multiple table data

Comment: you are calling the tables according to page number, so if the page number is one the first query will execute. so where is the problem that you are facing @MmdMahbub

Comment: This is mindless. But, what are you passing to the get parameter 'v' . Then, you can try debugging by putting echo statements in each if condition and see where it is going.

Comment: Have you check which if block it executed?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding $qri_res. You must use 3 variables or appending the data result.

Answer (score 0):

```
               $page = $_GET['v'];  
               $sel_data ="";

 if($page == 1){ $sel_data="SELECT * FROM fix ORDER BY fix_id DESC ";}

 if($page == 2){ $sel_data="SELECT * FROM seo ORDER BY seo_id DESC "; }                                                

 if($page == 3){ $sel_data="SELECT * FROM err ORDER BY err_id DESC "; }   

 $qri_res = mysqli_query($con,$sel_data);

 while($total_row=mysqli_fetch_array($qri_res)){
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a problem with string versus int.

**Use this to make it a safe INT:**

```
$page = (int)$_GET['v'];
```

**Use this to compare it**

```
if($page === 1){
```